# concat an object into an array in react native redux

Tags: react-native, redux

i have problem in concat an object into array using redux.
when user clicks button i want to concat object into array but always it shows an error called Cannot read property 'concat' of null.
here are my codes:

```js
  addToCartHandler= ()=>{
    const {phoneNumber,accessToken,ctr} = this.props;
    let {dataSource} = this.state;
    const cart = {title:dataSource.title,image:dataSource.image,id:dataSource.id,count:ctr,price:(dataSource.price-dataSource.discount)*ctr};
    this.props.onCart(cart);}
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onLogin: () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.SAVEPHONE }),
    onToken: token => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.SAVEACCESSTOKEN, token }),
    onCart:(cart)=>dispatch({type:actionTypes.CARTPRODUCT,cart})
  }
    
}
```

and this is my reducer:

```js
const initialState = {
   cartProduct:[],
}

const ShopReducer = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.CARTPRODUCT:
        return {
            ...state,
            cartProduct:state.cartProduct.concat(action.cart)
        }
        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concat an array with an object. instead wrap your object with an array as shown in the snippet

```js
const initialState = {
   cartProduct:[],
}

const ShopReducer = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.CARTPRODUCT:
        return {
            ...state,
            cartProduct:state.cartProduct.concat([action.cart]) // change here
        }
        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Not tested!!. Hope it helps :)

Comment: tested. not working.
it assumes cartProduct empty array as null . i dont know why

Comment: Verify that your ‘state.cartProduct’ is still an array then

Comment: If you are persisting the store to localstorage or something, clear it and start afresh, my guess here is your cartProduct is no longer an array because the previous implementation was failing